# Get Author email address in SharePoint Hosted App using JSOM

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created the SharePoint hosted app.

I'm using JSOM for App.

I'm retrieving items from the list.

I have default column in the list called **Author** (Created by).

I want to retrieve email address of that **Author**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below sample code. It gets the item by its ID, then get the created by field and then ensures the user exits in site collection using `web.EnsureUser`. After that, we can use the email property.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var item = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Custom List").getItemById(1);
clientContext.load(item);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){ 
       var createdBy = item.get_item("Author");
       var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(createdBy.get_lookupValue());
       clientContext.load(user);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){ 
                 var email = user.get_email();   
                 console.log("User Email: " + email);
            },function(sender,args){ 
                 console.log(args.get_message());
            }
       );
  },
  function(sender,args){ 
       console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```